# 'FlatSym' object has no attribute 'array'

Tags: python

I'm still learning to use FatSym to analyze medical images; But I keep getting this error 'FlatSym' object has no attribute 'array' This is my code

```
pip install numpy
pip install pylinac
from pylinac import FlatSym
my_file = r"C:\Users\xxxx.dcm"
my_img = FlatSym(path=my_file)
my_img.analyze(flatness_method='varian', symmetry_method='varian', vert_position=0.5, horiz_position=0.5)
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-0bda45c5e24c> in <module>
----> 1 my_img.analyze(flatness_method='varian', symmetry_method='varian', vert_position=0.5, horiz_position=0.5)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylinac\flatsym.py in analyze(self, flatness_method, symmetry_method, vert_position, horiz_position, vert_width, horiz_width)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylinac\flatsym.py in _calc_symmetry(self, method, vert_position, horiz_position, vert_width, horiz_width)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pylinac\flatsym.py in _get_vert_profile(self, vert_position, vert_width)

AttributeError: 'FlatSym' object has no attribute 'array'
```

What i'm missing here please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FlatSym you have imported is an object try this

```
from pylinac import FlatSym
my_file = r"C:\Users\xxxx.dcm"
my_img = FlatSym(my_file)
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I tried your solution and got this different error: 
```AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-0bda45c5e24c> in <module>
----> 1 my_img.analyze(flatness_method='varian', symmetry_method='varian', vert_position=0.5, horiz_position=0.5)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'analyze'```

Comment: sorry yakob the method you have followed is the right way FlatSym(path) i have made a mistake, but  there must be some kind of an issue with image file you are reading